# Oracle cannot read picture for ORDImage

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following directory to store images.

```
create or replace directory TEST AS '\home\oracle';
```

In this folder I have the picture name 'Pojazd.png'.
I hava tried to load this images into database via following script.

```
DECLARE
  l_image      ORDImage;
  l_ctx        RAW(4000)    := NULL;
  l_file_name  VARCHAR2(10) := 'Pojazd.png';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO foto_oferty (idk,nazwa_pliku,obrazek,oferta_id)
  VALUES (1,l_file_name,ORDSYS.ORDImage.init(),1);

  SELECT obrazek
  INTO   l_image
  FROM   foto_oferty
  WHERE  nazwa_pliku = l_file_name
  FOR UPDATE;

  -- Import the image into the database
  l_image.importFrom(l_ctx, 'file', 'TEST', 'Pojazd.png');

  UPDATE foto_oferty
  SET    obrazek     = l_image
  WHERE  nazwa_pliku = l_file_name;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

However I get the following error message.

```
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
No such file or directory
22288. 00000 -  "file or LOB operation %s failed\n%s"
*Cause:    The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed.
```

I don't understand what is the reason of this. I have defined the path and file exists there. I use virtualbox and oracle 11g machine.

[image]

Comment: are you on unix?  are you sure your slashes are going the right way?  make sure your user has read and write permissions on the directory.

Comment: @PeterM Oracle 11g on virtualbox is on unix.

Comment: @PeterM No difference between slashes the result is always the same.

Comment: which user created the directory vs which user is running the anonymous block?  try this -- select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name='TEST' -- to make sure the user has permissions on the directory

Comment: @PeterM I have used command grant read, write on directory TEST to public

Comment: @PeterM I have checked your query, no table or view exists.

Comment: wierd, you should get a row back where type ='DIRECTORY' and it should show one row for read one one row for write for TEST.  try it again but select from dba_tab_privs where type='DIRECTORY', also with linux it is case sensitive so double check your file name

Comment: @PeterM I have posted screen shot, table dba_tab_privs is empty nothing is there.

Comment: @PeterM I have checked query select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name='TEST' It exists.

Comment: @PeterM I have posted result from query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167272/discussion-between-maciejka-and-peter-m).